# Homestead - Vagrant:command not found

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have faced a very strange issue with Homestead on a mac.

I've installed vagrant, virtual box, homestead. When I run `homestead`, I see the full list of commands, but `homestead up` gives a *Vagrant: command not found* error. No idea what could be wrong, I already created and configured the Homestead.yaml file, `vagrant -v` gives me the correct version of vagrant, the problem appears only when I need to boot the homestead machine.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain the steps from the beginning so you can check if you did something wrong. I suggest you delete your homestead folder and try installing it again to see what happens.

Did you installed homestead locally or globally?

( like `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead` or  `composer global require laravel/homestead` )

If the answer is locally you need to go inside the folder created when you cloned homestead and then run this command to init the config files of homestead ( ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml)

```
bash init.sh
```

If you installed it globally you can use this command from anywhere. After that you just need to configure the Homestead.yaml file as explained in the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).
Only then you run

```
 homestead up
```

If it still doesn't work, try running `vagrant global-status` get the ID of your homestead vm and then run `vagrant up [machineId]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in folder of homestead folder. After you git clone homestead (https://github.com/laravel/homestead) cd in it and then try with command vagrant up or homestead up. Then vagrant will create and configure homestead machine according to homestead Vagrant file.

Also check vagrant documentation (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/up.html)